# Rails caching works only if I send the If-None-Match header manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

My rails code:

```
def index
  battles = Battle.feed(current_user, params[:category_name], params[:future_time])

  @battles = paginate battles, per_page: 50

  if stale?([@battles, current_user.id], template: false)
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

If I send the If-None-Match header with the last Etag manually I get 304 status code in return, If I don't send it manually (The header is sent automatically with the same If-None-Match header) I get 200 status code...

I'm checking the server using Postman rest client (Cache enabled).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on the Rails side of things here but this is correct behaviour if I'm following  you.

When sending "If-None-Match" you get a 304 if the content has not changed (same e-tag). This is basically saying either yourself or something in between such as a proxy has the content already and so does not need to transfer the body again.

If you omit the header then you see a 200. Postman by default will send a set of a headers but it's also pretty lean in the sense that it strips a lot away. Try the same request in your browser and you'll get a 304. You'll see your browser will be set to use caching where possible.

Things may get different if you are relying upon server side caching. You may be seeing what looks like a new response yet the server is actually doing very little yet yielding a 200 response.

To summarise the header is doing the right job from your description.

Comment: Hey, When I'm omit the header from postman I still get the same header in the logs, but something different happens when I add manually the header in Postman. Also I want to get 304 status code and not 200 cached status code

Comment: In the log are you saying when Postman does not send the header explicitly yet you see "If-None-Match"? Postman just runs on top of Chrome right, so it may be sending other headers in the background. I can't check at present but worth double checking - something like Fiddler or other tool can help here. Just to be clear, you should only get the 304 status code if you send "If-None-Match" or any other cache aware header.

Comment: I checked my rails logs, same headers, just diffrent cookie and postman-token